# Override resource in other configuration - Android studio

Tags: android, xml, copy

I'm new to android and I found a website where the author is explaining how to build an app and he shared his code. But when I copy the code to my android studio I get an error, and when I press alt+enter the only option I have is "Override resource in other configuration" but when I type the code it seems to be ok. Can anyone help me and give me a solution? Here is the code:

```
 <?xml version=”1.0" encoding=”utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android=
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools=”http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools=”http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:orientation=”vertical”
    android:background=”@drawable/bg”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    tools:context=”com.example.ekene.blogzone.PostActivity”>
<ImageButton
android:id=”@+id/imageBtn”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”250dp”
    android:adjustViewBounds=”true”
    android:scaleType=”centerCrop”
    android:src=”@drawable/add_img” />
<EditText
android:layout_marginTop=”20dp”
    android:id=”@+id/textTitle”
    android:background=”@drawable/edit_text_styles”
    android:padding=”10dp”
    android:textColor=”#fff”
    android:textStyle=”bold”
    android:hint=”Post Title”
    android:layout_marginRight=”5dp”
    android:layout_marginLeft=”5dp”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />
<EditText
android:background=”@drawable/edit_text_styles”
    android:padding=”10dp”
    android:layout_marginTop=”20dp”
    android:hint=”Post Description”
    android:textColor=”#fff”
    android:id=”@+id/textDesc”
    android:layout_marginRight=”5dp”
    android:layout_marginLeft=”5dp”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />
<Button
android:layout_marginTop=”30dp”
    android:id=”@+id/postBtn”
    android:textColor=”#fff”
    android:textStyle=”bold”
    android:layout_marginRight=”5dp”
    android:layout_marginLeft=”5dp”
    android:background=”@drawable/action_button_style”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:text=”Post”/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: In line 4 in your code it says  xmlns:android=  just delete it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of errors like

```
xmlns:android=
```

android.com/apk/res/android"
also a diff. kind of quote was present.

I have corrected it now it should work fine.

Here is the code :-

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ekene.blogzone.PostActivity">
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/add_img" />
<EditText
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textTitle"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_styles"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="Post Title"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText
android:background="@drawable/edit_text_styles"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Post Description"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/textDesc"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/postBtn"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/action_button_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Post"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, thank you :) I will continue building the app using the same site, but if I get any more errors I will post them here